# runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests steals my http post request parameters from an isapi handler

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have an old isapi application that I am now replacing with a new .NET one.

I set `<module runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` to route the request according to some rule, between the old isapi handler, and the new aspx page. I have the following code in my global aspx:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Path.EndsWith("oldisapi.dll",
         StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        if (UseDotNet)
            Context.RewritePath("/scripts/newpage.aspx");
    }
}
```

This works great, **except** when I receive an http POST request - the oldisapi.dll doesn't receive the request parameters.

If I remove the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` it receives the parameters, but the rerouting to the .NET aspx page doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of frustration I couldn't solve it, but I was able to avoid it.
If I don't access the parameters of the request, it will not steal them from the old isapi.
I only needed the cookies, so this worked out fine for me.